# how to code with css3 a list with cycles connected by vertical lines?

Tags: css, html-lists

CSS3 allows us to create list items (ol and ul) with help of HTML code. I need help on how to code an ordered list with the power of CSS. in this case, it's a list with cycles (like number 1 inside a cycle), and a verticle line connecting each list item as shown from this image.

As you'll see from the code, the results give a list without the big cycles as shown from this image. I would like it to be like this.

[image]

Thanks.

This is the CSS & HTML code:

```css
/* Experiences */
ul.experiences {
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
ul.experiences li {
    padding-left: 33px;
    margin-bottom: 2.5em;
    list-style: none;
    background: url('../img/misc/list-bullet-darkgray.png') no-repeat;
}
ul.experiences li.green {
    background: url('../img/misc/list-bullet-green.png') no-repeat;
}
ul.experiences li.blue {
    background: url('../img/misc/list-bullet-blue.png') no-repeat;
}
ul.experiences li.pink {
    background: url('../img/misc/list-bullet-pink.png') no-repeat;
}
.where {
    font-size: 1.2857em; /* 18/16 -> 18px */
    font-weight: 300;
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}
.what {
    font-size: 0.75em; /* 12/16 -> 12px */
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #444444;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 12px;
    margin: -5px 0.5em 0 0 !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.what.green {
    background-color: #c4df9b;
}
.what.blue {
    background-color: #6dcff6;
}
.what.pink {
    background-color: #f06eaa;
}
.when {
    float: right;
    color: #b9b9b9;
    font-style: italic;
}
.description {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}


/* BORDERS AND BULLETS */

p {
    /*CSS reset*/
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

ul.experiences li {
    position:relative; /* so that pseudoelements are positioned relatively to their "li"s*/
    /* use padding-bottom instead of margin-bottom.*/ 
    margin-bottom: 0; /* This overrides previously specified margin-bottom */
    padding-bottom: 2.5em;
}

ul.experiences li:after {
    /* bullets */
    content: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/30/RedDisc.svg/20px-RedDisc.svg.png');
    position: absolute;
    left: -26px; /*adjust manually*/
    top: 0px;
}

ul.experiences li:before {
    /* lines */
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    left: -16px; /* adjust manually */
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    height: 100%;
    width: 1px;
}

ul.experiences li:first-child:before {
   /* first li's line */
   top: 6px; /* moves the line down so that it disappears under the bullet. Adjust manually */
}

ul.experiences li:last-child:before {
    /* last li's line */
   height: 6px; /* shorten the line so it goes only up to the bullet. Is equal to first-child:before's top */
}
```

```html
<ul class="experiences">

  <!-- Experience -->
  <li class="green">
    <div class="where">New York Times</div>
    <h3 class="what green">Senior Online Editor</h3>
    <div class="when">2012 - Present</div>
    <p class="description">Jelly-o pie chocolate cake...</p>
   </li>
  <li class="green">
    <div class="where">New York Times</div>
    <h3 class="what green">Senior Online Editor</h3>
    <div class="when">2012 - Present</div>

    <p class="description">Jelly-o pie chocolate cake...</p>
   </li>
  <li class="green">
    <div class="where">New York Times</div>
    <h3 class="what green">Senior Online Editor</h3>
    <div class="when">2012 - Present</div>

    <p class="description">Jelly-o pie chocolate cake...</p>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: added the Code as requested.

Answer (score 0):

How about something along the lines of

```
li {
    position: relative;
}
li::before {
    background: green;
    opacity: 0.5;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -15px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 100%;
}
li::after {
    border: 2px solid green;
    border-radius: 100%;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -20px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

and change `<ul></ul>` to `<ol></ol>`

Comment: yes, that was almost working. it's exactly what I wanted (as per design) but it doesn't list the numbers. I followed your code and I can share CSS here.